# Как вызвать функцию в текущей сессии

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как вызвать функцию в рамках одной сессии?

```js
function addGifBlockPage() {
  $('<div id="gifblock" class="gif-block"><img src="https://img-fotki.yandex.ru/get/194503/65387414.f54/0_1cdd3b_e80e1107_S"></div>').appendTo('.main');
}

addGifBlockPage();

var gifblock = document.getElementById("gifblock");
sessionStorage.setItem('gifblock', addGifBlockPage);


if (sessionStorage.getItem("addGifBlockPage") == null) {
  $(".gif-block").show();
}

var timerId = setTimeout(function() {
  $('.gif-block').hide();
}, 5000);
```

```css
.main {
  width: 400px;
  height: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #656565;
}

.gif-block {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  width: 101px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: -50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main"></div>
```

Comment: Что такое сессия?

Comment: промежуток времени когда пользователь находится на сайте, в данном контексте при переходи со страницы не на страницу не вызывать функцию постоянно, а пока пользователь на сайте вызвать один раз. если закрыл старницу или браузер а потом снова зашел на страниу вызвать один раз.

Comment: Можно сохранить факт выполнения функции в sessionStorage

Comment: а есть пример какой нибудь?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_webstorage_session

Comment: поправил пример но так и непонял до конца, пока что не работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (!sessionStorage.getItem("addGifBlockPage")) {
  sessionStorage.setItem('addGifBlockPage', true);
  $(".gif-block").show();
}
```